# How to loop collection object in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to foreach loop in laravel.Here is my print_r result of jobseekers.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( 
    [items:protected] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 37 [max(call_back_date)] => 2018-12-12 ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 60 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-12-12 ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 61 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-30 ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 73 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-29 ) 
        [4] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 62 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-28 ) 
        [5] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 63 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-22 ) 
        [6] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 64 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-15 ) 
        [7] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 66 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-15 ) 
        [8] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 65 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-10 ) 
        [9] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 54 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-10-24 ) 
        [10] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 53 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-09-30 ) 
        [11] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 48 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-09-20 ) 
        [12] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 46 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-08-26 ) 
        [13] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 58 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-12-12 ) 
        [14] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 70 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-11-29 ) 
        [15] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 47 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-08-20 ) 
        [16] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 44 [max(call_back_date)] => 2017-08-18 ) 
        [17] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 72 [max(call_back_date)] => 2018-02-17 ) 
        [18] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 55 [max(call_back_date)] => 2000-12-12 ) 
        [19] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 49 [max(call_back_date)] => ) 
        [20] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 50 [max(call_back_date)] => ) 
        [21] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 74 [max(call_back_date)] => ) 
        [22] => stdClass Object ( [myid] => 32 [max(call_back_date)] => ) 
    ) 
)
```

and i tried like this

```
foreach ($jobseekers as  $value) {
   echo $value->myid;
}
```

it shows me only the first item. like "37", i expect many items. like "37,60,61 etc...".

Comment: using method  `->first();`

Comment: this is my query " $jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
              ->select(DB::raw("max(id) as myid,max(call_back_date)"))
                ->orderBy('call_back_date','desc')
              ->groupBy('jobseeker_id')  
              ->get();"

Comment: `$jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')->select(DB::raw("max(id) as myid,max(call_back_date)"))->orderBy('call_back_date','desc')->groupBy('jobseeker_id')->first();`

Comment: @ThanHtutOo  Are you sure you have this much `foreach()` loop code only.Also are you sure `37` is printing? Do you have any other code with this `foreach()`? If yes `show us that code.` (add some more code for clarafication)

Comment: Yes @AlivetoDie , thats why i am asking for the helps man, i am also confuse about it.

Comment: use dump() or dd() to dump the values

Comment: @ThanHtutOo  you have to show complete code then

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do more one loop to iterate the data.

---

update

try one of this

```
foreach($jobseekers ->items as value){}
```

or this

```
foreach ($jobseekers as  $value) {
       foreach ($value as  $item) {}
}
```

Comment: can u guide me?

Comment: you can iterate a collection, you dont have to pull the items from it yourself